# Firebase was unable to find an index.html for my nextjs app

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I'm aware that next build doesn't produce an index.html, but according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs, firebase should integrate with it. this is my next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
headers() {
return [
{
source: "/firebase/firebaseWorker.js",
headers: [{ key: "Content-Type", value: "application/javascript" }],
},
];
},
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Next export is unable to find a production build in the .next directory

I've tried adding 'output: 'export'' and removing the headers, but it throws the same error. Considering I'm using server side rendering, I feel like this may not be a very good solution anyway.  I've also made sure my firebase.json has public: ".next" This is my first time deploying so sorry if it's a dumb issue, but I don't really know where to proceed.